# Changing label caption on UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to use a "x + 1" function to change a label in a UserForm. The label caption is not changing.

My label (SalesForm.BHSDROWLABELLF) caption being 1, I want to click a button and turn the caption from 1 to 2.

```vb
Private Sub BHSDNEXTTAPBUTTONLF_Click()

X = SalesForm.BHSDROWLABELLF.Caption

X = X + 1

SalesForm.BHSDADDRESSLF.Value = Worksheets("GG").Cells(X, 23)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can be drastically reduced to

```
Private Sub BHSDNEXTTAPBUTTONLF_Click()
    With BHSDROWLABELLF
        .Caption = Val(.Caption) + 1

        BHSDADDRESSLF.Value = Worksheets("GG").Cells(.Caption, 23)
    End With
End Sub
```

I am assuming that the name of the form is `SalesForm`

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub BHSDNEXTTAPBUTTONLF_Click()
   Dim X as Variant
   '@T.M comment > use Me instead of SalesForm
   X = Me.BHSDROWLABELLF.Caption
   If IsNumeric(X) Then
      X = Val(X) + 1
   
      Me.BHSDROWLABELLF.Caption = X  ' Cstr(X)  @Siddharth Rout comment

      Me.BHSDADDRESSLF.Value = Worksheets("GG").Cells(X, 23)
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. you can get rid of `Cstr()`

Comment: Just a hint: I'd omit the `SalesForm.`-prefix, as the label event is executed from within the form's (class) code module behind. Consider to use the `Me.` particle with the further advantage of intellisense by typing `Me.`

Comment: @T.M. I figured, I'm very new to VBA and i figured being incredibly specific wouldn't be a bad move. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 2):

The question is adding 1 to the label caption when clicking the button.

```
Private Sub BHSDNEXTTAPBUTTONLF_Click()
Me.BHSDROWLABELLF.Caption = Me.BHSDROWLABELLF.Caption + 1
End Sub
```